# Fusion Tables PHP Framework - getting sample file to work: form_example.php

Tags: google-fusion-tables

When I run the Fusion Tables PHP Framework sample file "form_example.php" I get the following errors:

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\php\fusion-tables-client-php\clientlogin.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\php\form_example.php on line 31

Any help is greatly appreciated.  My main goal is to test code that can insert a row into Fusion Tables from data entered in a form.

Thanks -

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like ClientLogin is failing. The following stack overflow question might be helpful:

[Can't connect to HTTPS site using cURL. Returns 0 length content instead. What can I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316099/cant-connect-to-https-site-using-curl-returns-0-length-content-instead-what-c)

Comment: Thanks Kathryn - am moving on to the Python libraries and OAuth 2.0 per your comments on the GFT sites.  Thanks again!