# Download image from https sources

Tags: php, https

I have enabled OpenId for my website. However when I want to download and save the user avatars to my server, I can't. I have tried several methods but none of them worked. I should note that my script works just fine for http files so for example it will for [THIS FILE](http://static.php.net/www.php.net/images/php.gif) but not for [THIS URL](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-bqGMjCEXnZ0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/-Q-Ig7u-qvw/s27-c/photo.jpg). I know I can change `https` to `http` and download the image. But I wonder what should I do to download the file from `https`?

Comment: We're gonna need more information, how you're fetching these images (curl, file_ge_contents), and, what's the error? Maybe it's some google limitation ... You can also access all picasa photos without https, just replace the https by http and fetch the image

Comment: As I said, I have tried several methods, however the easiest one is `copy($url, $filename);` (which is working right now)

Comment: `copy` uses `file_get_contents` to download file, if you tried with curl and didn't work, check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316099/cant-connect-to-https-site-using-curl-returns-0-length-content-instead-what-c 
It's working now, but if for some reason it stops, try to use `fsockopen`

Comment: _"I want to download [...] I can't"_. Please tell why not. What method do you use, and what errors do you get?

Comment: @CodeCaster: As I said in the comments and the question itself, I've used a few methods such as the `copy` function, `file_get_contents`, `cURL` and any other method I found on the net. None of them worked. As for the first part of your question: `why not`, I don't know why not. That's the reason I asked the question. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OS do you use? Make sure PHP is compiled with OpenSSL support. In some distributions you have to install a package like php-openssl for method like file_get_contents or cURL to work on SSL.

Comment: I'm on Windows. How can I know if it's supported?

Comment: Check out the output of `<?php echo phpinfo();?>` and look if the OpenSSL module is loaded. If it’s not, try to add it on your php.ini. Something like `extension=php_openssl.dll` should work.