# how to insert data in to google fusion table form iphone app

Tags: ios, google-fusion-tables

I want to insert data from my iPhone app to fusion table my fusion table is private, my select query in working properly if i insert data manually in to fusion but i don't want to insert data manually in want when my app get value that vale has to insert in to fusion table, i referred google API Documentation, i read this also [Insertion into google fusion table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262526/insertion-into-google-fusion-table) but still i m not understanding how to implement this can please any one guide me for this.
  Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use a so called [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount). You can create such accounts in the [Google API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/). A Service Account acts as a deputy of the user. You can make calls to the API, change data etc. Just make sure that the Service Account has correct permission on the table you want to edit.

Comment: i have created Service Account, access token also but and i am using POST method on https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query? this URL but i am getting this msg: "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter: sql",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "sql"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required parameter: sql"
 }
}
Please can you help what's going wrong

Comment: You need to provide the sql parameter in your request (for POST in the body). Something like `sql=INSERT into xyz values(...)`

Comment: Is there an API library for iOS that supports service accounts? From the google docs- "The mechanics of this interaction require applications to create and cryptographically sign JWTs. Developers are strongly encouraged to use an existing library to perform these tasks."

Comment: @David: There are [many libraries](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/libraries), and afaik they all support Service Accounts. The one for Objective-C might be the choice for iOS.

Comment: The objective-c library uses the google-toolbox for mac oauth sdk which doesn't seem to support service accounts.  according to this link- https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount, only java, python and php support creating JWT's?