# Dailymotion API request returning blank result

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I am using the following code to retrieve video ID, title, thumbnail, duration and tags.

```
$dailymotion = "https://api.dailymotion.com/video/xreczc?fields=title,duration,thumbnail_url,id,tags";
$curl = curl_init($dailymotion);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$results = json_decode($return, true);
print_r($results);
```

However it returns empty/blank page. I am using this on my localhost what could be wrong? I can call https://api.dailymotion.com/video/xreczc?fields=title,duration,thumbnail_url,id,tags directly in the browser and it works.

Any help, or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to fix it.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.dailymotion.com/video/".$id."?fields=id,title,thumbnail_url,tags,duration,embed_url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$results = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$results = json_decode($results);
if (!$results || $results->error->code) {
    return false;
} else {
    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this one.

```
$dailymotion = file_get_contents("https://api.dailymotion.com/video/xreczc?fields=title,duration,thumbnail_url,id,tags");

$results = json_decode($dailymotion, true);

print_r($results);
```

Comment: You shouldn't disable verifying ssl certificates. Your code does just that. They are there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fetch a https link via curl which has known issues. See the following links to see if they help your issue.

[Can't connect to HTTPS site using cURL. Returns 0 length content instead. What can I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316099/cant-connect-to-https-site-using-curl-returns-0-length-content-instead-what-c)

http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Regards,