# Getting no content from a HTTPS connection using CURL

Tags: c++, curl, https

I've been trying to learn more about CURL recently and finally managed to compile and install it properly as a static library for my test project. Eventually I'll move on to learning about posting forms and such.

I've successfully managed to connect and print out page content from `http://www.google.se`.

When connecting to a secure http page `https://www.google.se` I get an empty string as page content.

I'm using [this](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTTIMEOUT) to get information about the options.

I've tried the things from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/316732/944301), but it didn't work or I did it wrong.
I also tried turning off verifypeer and verifyhost (though I really want to practice safe solutions), but it didn't work either.

What do I need to do to make it work?
Am I doing something wrong?

---

Here's the test code

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;

static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp){
    ((string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

int main(){
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  string readBuffer;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl){
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.se");
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

    //Doesn't seem to work
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "path\\cacert.pem");

    //Neither does this
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    cout<<readBuffer<<endl;

    system("pause");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

### Update

So I got the error message from curl saying `Unsupported protocol`, which I'm guessing is what it says when SSL doesn't work. So I had to recompile it with SSL (which is odd, because I thought I did the first time) but...

I'm almost about to give up. Sigh. For some reason or other, now it gave me the error
`NMAKE: fatal error U1077 nasmw` when making the SSL, even though I clearly gave it the right %PATH% to nasm. I followed the steps to the letter.

So I tried using the [curl binaries of type libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.27.0/dist-w32/curl-7.27.0-devel-mingw32.zip), but I don't know how to link it properly in VC++ because the library files are unfamiliar to me.

I keep getting these linker errors when trying to compile the test project.

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_cleanup referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_strerror referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_perform referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_setopt referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_init referenced in function _main
```

So frustrated... I wish I understood why it has to be so complicated.
I just want to use the library already!

---

### Update 2

Ok... I managed to compile the curl library with SSL and reporting `CURL_VERSION_SSL` is enabled

```
curl_version_info_data * vinfo = curl_version_info(CURLVERSION_NOW);

if(vinfo->features & CURL_VERSION_SSL){
    cout<<"CURL: SSL enabled"<<endl;
}else{
    cout<<"CURL: SSL not enabled"<<endl;
}

//Prints out "CURL: SSL enabled"
```

but I'm still getting the same error message `Unsupported protocol`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You should also check for any errors after each curl_ function call as suggested (and accepted as answer) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316099/cant-connect-to-https-site-using-curl-returns-0-length-content-instead-what-c/316732#316732)

Comment: @fvu Oh, right. Forgot about the error reporting. It says "Unsupported protocol". Sounds like I may have forgotten to compile CURL with SSL support. That's a stupid mistake. Sorry :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, after I'd compiled the library for the nth time, everything seemed fine until I debugged it and it gave me heap errors, suggesting I made a mistake *twitch twitch* again.

Before starting a new compiling session I took another look around the curl.haxx and found an MSVC package. It made me gleeful, because I know how to handle those! I chose the static library, because that's what I wanted.

Though, not everything went smoothly, I had to add some additional linker dependencies for it to work properly.

namely

```
#pragma comment(lib, "curllib_static.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "wldap32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ssleay32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "openldap.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libeay32.lib")
```

Put those in and used the certificate bundle from the other package I downloaded so that I could connect to HTTPS.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "_path_\ca-bundle.crt");
```

I am getting a few warnings though, warnings I've never seen before. They don't mess anything up, but it's got something to do with the PDB file "vc90", something I thought VC++ handled by itself.

Here's the code connecting to `https://www.google.se` (pragmas removed and added in linker dependencies under project properties) after ***finally*** having a proper CURL library.

Here's the [MSVC package](http://curl.haxx.se/download/libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc.zip) (SSL Enabled). You can use one of the scripts (perl or VBscript) from [this package](http://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.27.0/dist-w32/curl-7.27.0-devel-mingw32.zip) to make the certificate bundle for you.

Oh, also, if you're using a static library like me, you have to add the preprocessor definition `CURL_STATICLIB`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;

static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp){
    ((string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

int main(){
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  string readBuffer;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl){
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.se");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:\\libcurl_static\\ca-bundle.crt");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    cout<<readBuffer<<endl;

    system("pause");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Was really my fault, I should've checked the description on the download wizard they have. I only downloaded the latest source from the archives (7.27.0) because I thought I ***had*** to compile it myself to get what I wanted.

This whole thing is embarrassing. I learned a lot from it though.

Answer (score 1):

Use -v to inspect the full response. It is probably a redirect. Also, Google is known to block requests done with curl's default user-agent...