# How to set up curl for https support in cpp

Tags: c++, curl, cryptography, openssl, libcurl

I managed to run `curl` for `http` in my programs, but I fail miserably when I try to make `https` connections.

I will always end up with the `unsupported protocol` error.

```
 if( vinfo->features & CURL_VERSION_SSL )
 {
     f << "LIBCURL: SSL Support Enabled\n" << endl;
 }
```

Won't be triggered. I am using the pre-compiled curl version with SSL support (I guess)

Using curl `Win32 2000/XP   7.29.0  libcurl     SSL         Günter Knauf    3.29 MB` from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html / direct: http://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.29.0/dist-w32/curl-7.29.0-devel-mingw32.zip

Thanks for the help

Comment: is the unsupported protocol message appearing in the else part of that if by any chance?

Comment: This may help.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/316732/16287

Comment: it comes in `if(res != CURLE_OK)f << curl_easy_strerror(res) << endl;` if I'm trying to access an https page

Comment: @DrewDormann that sadly didn't change it