# cURL works in terminal — error in PHP json

Tags: php, json, curl

I looked through all of the other terminal vs. PHP questions and couldn't find a solve.

I'm working with data API and this works to retrieve a list of files:

What am I missing in the translation?

```
PHP CODE:
$url = 'https://api-url';
$data = array(
    'header' => array(
        'id' => '1',
    ),
    'others' => array(
        "details" => yes,
    ),    
);

$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                 


$ch = curl_init($url);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Terminal code:(Working fine)

```
curl -X POST -d '{"header": {"id": 1}, "others": {"details": yes}' --user "u-p" 'https://api-url'
```

Comment: I suspect https issue, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316099/cant-connect-to-https-site-using-curl-returns-0-length-content-instead-what-c

Comment: You forgot to translate `--user` option:
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '4VDesucr5xcoNXETjTXvEkjhoZX5fghctDlsrNIfRM:lkjS7@ZXmv3');`

Comment: It's not SSL. If it was SSL, it is more likely a man-in-the-middle attack - a serious company always offers valid SSL certs. In Addition, you should not post private key or credential information publicy in your question (if this is the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add for ssl

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

Also you need to check your API host and sending data  it's giving error like:-

```
"{"result":"failed","errorMessage":"expected HTTP authorization, \"client_id\" property, or \"integration\" property","errorCode":"system.error"}"
```

Answer (score 2):

1) You forgot to translate `--user` option. Its counterpart in PHP libcurl is `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option.

2) As has already written in the comments you have to disable SSL peer verification by setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` option to `false`.

3) You shouldn't set `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` and `CURLOPT_POST` options together, only one of them (`CURLOPT_POST` in your case).

So the code should look like this:

```
...
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'username/password',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
    ),
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: @Ketan I forgot to add `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option to the final code. See updated answer