# PHP cURL https no error, not working

Tags: php, curl

I'm really confused by this.  My company recently switched this URL to http**s**, and I can no longer make cURL requests against it.  No one else in the company does PHP, so there's no one to help me debug.

I don't have much experience with https, so I read through a bunch of posts on here and found a few that addressed this same issue, namely, this one:

[Can't connect to HTTPS site using cURL. Returns 0 length content instead. What can I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316099/cant-connect-to-https-site-using-curl-returns-0-length-content-instead-what-c)

At first, I was getting all sorts of errors related to security certificates, but after adding `curl.cainfo="c:\xampp\htdocs\login\cacert.pem"` to my `php.ini` file, I believe I have resolved those as I am not getting **errors** anymore, but I am still not getting back a successful login response.

As part of the process, I need to pass a cookie to the server, which *is* present.  `echo $strCookie` gives back the correct cookie data, so I don't think it's that.

```
$searchURL = "https://url.com/valid?";

$ch = curl_init();             
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $searchURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
$strCookie = 'testcookie=' . $_COOKIE['testcookie'] . '; path=/';    
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, "\cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

    if($answer = curl_exec($ch))
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($answer);
    echo "</pre>";
}
else
{    
    echo "<pre>";
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

If I put the url into my browser (`url.com/valid?`), I get back `boolean = true`, so I know I am logged in.  However, this script is returning `boolean = false` and I cannot figure out why.

**Here are the headers:**

```
TTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 09 Nov 2015 21:33:16 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 14
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
Set-Cookie: amlbcookie=01; domain=.****.com; path=/
Vary: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
```

I'm confused by the `Set-Cookie: amlbcookie=01` line, as I'm not sure what that cookie is.  It does not match the output I get from `echo $strCookie`.

Comment: just a guess but you should probably not run `curl_exec` twice instead run it once and then check against what it returns.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to do that since I don't define it prior to `if(curl_exec($ch) == false)` - the only way I knew of to output it was to assign to to a variable `$answer`, then `print_r` that.

Comment: try something like `if($answer = curl_exec($ch)){  //no error } else { //error }`

Comment: ok cool - that works.  Good catch. I'm still getting the same response though - `boolean = false`, so the issue still remains :)

Comment: have you attempted setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false` ?

Comment: try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, FALSE); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);` before your execute and see if that gives you any direction

Comment: @cmorrissey - yes. I believe I need to verify.  Without it, I still get the same server response so I really can't say.  The query doesn't return "true" whether I turn this to TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: @iam-decoder - the query isn't failing, it's going through, it's just giving me `boolean = false` to signify I'm not signed in.  The headers I have in my post are from `CURLOPT_HEADER`.

Comment: does the cookie contain the information necessary to tell if you're logged in? or does the server itself manage that?

Comment: the server itself manages that I believe.

Comment: @BrianPowell then that's your problem, you need to send something that the server can use to recreate the client's session for the call. When CURLing, it's creating a new instance where the server is asking the server for information.